# How can I create a font similar to this one?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, typography, font-design

I want to make a logo and the only font that fits what I need is [Ugo](https://www.behance.net/gallery/15397407/UGO-Typeface-Free-Font). However, I would prefer to use it in lowercase but there are no lowercase characters available.

How can I go about making mine?

[image: Ugo Font Sample]

Comment: you're going to do it in Illustrator, and it's just for this logo? If you don't have to create the whole alphabet, just get a similar round font and recreate the bevel effect / shadow you see here for the few letters you'll use.

Comment: Just to be clear.. you don't actually want to create a font (as in a file you can install and use on a computer) but recreate the look of that existing font for a logo, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a receipe for your font, but some possiblities to explore. Note, that in logo you do not need a full installed font, only what's needed.

For logos you can start from an existing font and modify it.  Write your text, convert it to outlines (=editable curves), edit and add effects. An example:

[image]

You probably need only to extrude, maybe also to expand to be able to select colors and strokes to certain parts. But you need a close enough font to start from.This is a good candidate

[image]

It's one stroke font - not extremely difficult to draw over a model. Only select rounded stroke ends. See an example:

[image]

There's only a problem: Copying a font, even by free hand, is piratism, if the character outlines are copyrighted. It's a hefty job, too. So purchase the font or use a free one similar enough.

Comment: @Mr. T Here's a receipe, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own fonts from scratch it is a detailed work.
But it should be fun too . Although i always wanted to create mine, my adventure with creating  fonts remained with adding new characters to an existing font.
Here is a small guide to give you a direction .

[First] you should learn about anatomy of letters. Some Characters has same width like E and F ; G and C.. There are some rules also that related with the effect of the lines on the eye . If you draw vertical contour and horizontal contour with same width, horizontal will look thicker. So usually horizontal contours are drawn thinner than the vertical ones to balance this illusion.

[FONT ANATOMY](http://typedia.com/learn/only/anatomy-of-a-typeface/)

[Anatomy of a Letterform](https://designmodo.com/letterform/)

[Second] Design your font on a vector or photo editing software . At least draw  some letters that will be a base for others. Like "g" can be used as a base for "y" .

[Third] You need a software . I used Fontforge [opensource] for editing my fonts. Fontforge has all tools to create a font file. Not best-user-friendly but does the job.

You should draw all characters there that you want to include in your font and font family. Exported files will work on operating systems.

Font forge has layers in order to help you drawing.. you can import images on background and draw over them.

Here i drew an "A" letter from an image and it get visible on font list.

[image]